# How can you see if there is a criminal complaint against somebody in Germany?

Tags: germany, criminal-record

How can you see or know if there is a civil or criminal complaint against somebody in Germany? Is there a way to check this on Google?

Comment: No, this would be an immense due process and privacy violation. Maintaining a database of convictions is explicitly illegal for the private sector. To find out if someone was convicted of significant crimes, you'd have to ask them for their Führungszeugnis.

Comment: @amon: ... which they, depending on who you are, do not have to give you. Also most of the entries are deleted after a specified time.

Answer (score 3):

Generally you can't, since a basic **Personality rights** exist for eveyone that must be balanced with public interest.

Allthough court proceedings are generally public, even the publication of when court sessions take place are very restrictive in the amount of information given out about what the session is about. How a court publishes this information seems to differ from court to court: public notice inside the court, press releases and sometimes an internet list.

Indictments, generally,  may not be published before the proceedings begin ([§ 353d StGB](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/englisch_stgb/englisch_stgb.html#p3298)).

#### Proceedings before an Indictment

Since an Indictment will only be accepted by a court if the chances are that it more likely succeed than fail, you may assume that the police or state attorneys will be **even more restrictive** about publicizing any information about any *criminal complaint* (or investigation).

---

So the answer to your question, based on the reasons above is:

- no, there is no way to check this on google (from official sources)

---

**Sources**:

- [Öffentlichkeitsgrundsatz - Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%96ffentlichkeitsgrundsatz) (German)

  - [Article 6 of the European Convention on Human Rights - Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Article_6_of_the_European_Convention_on_Human_Rights#:%7E:text=Article%206%20reads%20as%20follows,impartial%20tribunal%20established%20by%20law.)
  - [§ 169 - Courts Constitution Act
    (Gerichtsverfassungsgesetz – GVG)](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/englisch_gvg/englisch_gvg.html#p0808)

    - Publicity
    - [Justiz-Ticker - Berlin.de](https://www.berlin.de/gerichte/presse/justizticker/)
- [§ 353d StGB - Unlawful disclosure concerning judicial hearings](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/englisch_stgb/englisch_stgb.html#p3298)

Comment: Thank you by the information Mark!